# Mysql mixing SHA2 + MD5password

Tags: c++, mysql, hash

simple question.
I maded a server->client network , this store password intro a mysql database and it used by server to auth.

I want to salt it.

```
if(Login_IsInChannelService(szLogin))
{
    sys_log(0, "ChannelServiceLogin [%s]", szLogin);

    DBManager::instance().ReturnQuery(
        QID_AUTH_LOGIN,
        dwKey,
        p,
        "SELECT '%s',password,social_id,id,status,availDt - NOW() > 0,"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(silver_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(gold_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(safebox_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(autoloot_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fish_mind_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(marriage_fast_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(money_drop_rate_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) "
        "FROM account WHERE login='%s'",
        szPasswd,
        szLogin
    );
}
else
{
    DBManager::instance().ReturnQuery(
        QID_AUTH_LOGIN,
        dwKey,
        p,
        "SELECT id,SHA2('%s',224),password,social_id,status,availDt - NOW() > 0,"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(silver_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(gold_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(safebox_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(autoloot_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fish_mind_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(marriage_fast_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(money_drop_rate_expire),"
        "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) "
        "FROM account WHERE login='%s'",
        szPasswd,
        szLogin
    );
}
```

Actually i use sha2 for hashing but still easy to find hash.
Some ideeas how should i add salt for hash ?
This is the line responsable with sha2 hash

```
"SELECT id,SHA2('%s',224),password,social_id,status,availDt - NOW() > 0,"
```

If you need aditional info tell me.

Comment: What you need is neither SHA2 nor MD5 (crying), but *PBKDF2*

Comment: It's worth noting that both of these password hashing methods are really inadequate and you should be using something more robust like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) at the very least. Where SHA2 is just plain weak, MD5 is just plain *sad*. It's barely better than plain-text these days.